# How to check if my Application was correctly deployed by Wildfly 8.2.1 programmatically?

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, wildfly, jmx

I need to check the deployment status of my application which is deployed by Wildfly 8.2.1 programmatically (preferably java). As far I am concerned, there can be multiple ways to achieve this:

1. monitoring the semaphore files in the deployment folder (like if deployed there are .deployed files created for the war files).
2. check by calling a rest service which is supposed to be available when the war file is successfully deployed
3. using JMX mbeans

There might be other ways too, which I am not yet aware of. But I am more interested in learning the ways of using **JMX mbeans**. But unfortunately my online search is not giving me any good direction. If anyone can shed some light to this that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use management operations to check to see if you're deployment exists. It's a little old, but there's a [tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Detyped+management+and+the+jboss-dmr+library) on the deypted API.

```java
try (final ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9990)) {
    final ModelNode op = Operations.createOperation("read-children-resources");
    op.get(ClientConstants.CHILD_TYPE).set(ClientConstants.DEPLOYMENT);
    final ModelNode result = client.execute(op);
    if (Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(result)) {
        final ModelNode deployments = Operations.readResult(result);
        for (String deploymentName : deployments.keys()) {
            final ModelNode deploymentDetails = deployments.get(deploymentName);
            // do stuff
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to list deployments: " + Operations.getFailureDescription(result).asString());
    }
}
```

From the result you can read various information about the deployment. The output looks like:

```
{
    "content" => [{"hash" => bytes {
        0x77, 0x1f, 0x1a, 0xa1, 0x9e, 0x46, 0x11, 0x75,
        0x2f, 0x58, 0xce, 0x1b, 0x01, 0x29, 0x45, 0x43,
        0x16, 0x87, 0x22, 0x9a
    }}],
    "enabled" => true,
    "enabled-time" => 1443485828919L,
    "enabled-timestamp" => "2015-09-28 17:17:08,919 PDT",
    "name" => "batch-chunk.war",
    "owner" => undefined,
    "persistent" => true,
    "runtime-name" => "batch-chunk.war",
    "subdeployment" => undefined,
    "subsystem" => {
        "jaxrs" => undefined,
        "batch" => undefined,
        "undertow" => undefined
    }
}
```

If you wanted to see whether it was enabled you could do

```java
if (!deploymentDetails.get("enabled")) {
    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Deployment %s is not enabled", deploymentName);
}
```